# Sort hash keys by constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a table of order_states.

I have different clients with different labels for their states.

I am grabbing the all the clients and their states in a hash like this:

```
"client one" => {"shipped" => "state_zay", "ordered" => "state_bla"},
"client two" => {"shipped" => "state_bar", "ordered" => "state_foo"}
```

The constant would look something like this:

```
ordered, shipped
```

The result would look like this:

```
"client one" => {"ordered" => "state_bla", "shipped" => "state_zay"},
"client two" => {"ordered" => "state_foo", "shipped" => "state_bar"}
```

Note: I don't want them sorted alphabetically or numerically.

I want to have a contestant that represents the correct order for the states then order the keys based on that constant.

How does one go about that?

Comment: Can you give an example of the `constant` and your expected result?

Comment: this might help: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired output by doing so

```
hash = {"client one"=>{"ordered"=>"state_bla", "shipped"=>"state_zay"},
 "client two"=>{"ordered"=>"state_foo", "shipped"=>"state_bar"}}
hash.each do |key,value|
  hash[key] = value.sort_by{|key,value| value}.to_h
end
puts hash # This will be the sorted hash
```

Comment: it need to be sorted by an array, not alphabetically.